# Modifying sql table after i input something

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing

I am building a java project which is supossed to be used for a drugstore.I have an sql table which i use to keep the quantity and price of the products in stock. I have a buy option that i use to input what product i want to buy and in what quantity.But i cant manage to decrease the quantity i have in stock with the input i give the buy panel.(e.g. If i have 20 bricks in stock and i buy 10, after i press the buy button my database should have only 10 left.)

this is my what i tried :

```
    private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
        try{
            String sql="UPDATE stock SET quantity=quantity-? WHERE name=?";
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/stock","root","");
            pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1,product.getText());
            pst.setString(2,quantity2.getText());
            pst.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Purchase completed");

        }
        catch(SQLException | HeadlessException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
        }
}
```

Comment: In your query, first parameter goes to quantity, second to product name and it looks like you first set product name and then the quantity. Also assuming the quantity is some type of a number, better to use something similar to `setInt`.

Comment: i understand, Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about SQL but assuming you can do math in the SQL expression you have two problems with your `PreparedStatement`:

1. You must replace the "?" in the order in which they are defined in the SQL string.
2. you would want to pass an integer parameter for the value to reduce the quantity, not a String value.

So the code would be something like:

```
//pst.setString(1,product.getText());
//pst.setString(2,quantity2.getText());
pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(quantity2.getText());
pst.setString(2, product.getText());
```

Note you also need to replace the "?" in the order in which they are defined in your SQL string.

Comment: Thx for the feedback, i modified the query but it doesnt work because i dont know how get the quantity from the stock for me to use to calculate the updated quantity.

Comment: @LaurentiuRadut, I was just in the middle of updating my answer.  Your original SQL appears to be correct. The issue would be your usage of the PreparedStatement and the replacement of the parameters. New code should be correct.